# The results of tf.pow and torch.pow are different

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to convert PyTorch scripts to Tensorflow.
This is the situation.

```
>>> a=np.random.rand(500,500)
>>> b=tf.pow(tf.constant(a, tf.float32),2)
>>> c=torch.pow(torch.tensor(a, dtype=torch.float32),2)
>>> np.sum(b.numpy() - c.numpy())
3.2455164e-06
```

I **guess** this difference is caused by floating-point representations between the two platform. (I am not sure)

Questions
Do I need to make them exactly the same with each other?
If so how do solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to? How can we know?

Comment: Nope, I don't really need to since the results seem to be alright, but I just don't know this is well-known phenomena and acceptable.

Comment: I would say that it is common. Try printing mean absolute difference -- it is probably more informative and should be much smaller than what you have.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it can be some kind of bugs. I also checked the mean absolute differences. It is less than 1e-5, I think I can ignore this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments already say, this is a common issue.
`float32` only provides 6 digits of precision, which is what you see, since the difference is smaller than e-06. So as the comments already mentioned this is usual beheviour, if you need more precision you might want to use `float64`.

There was already a github [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18427) regarding this "problem", which was explained by albanD, who I took this information from.

Comment: Thanks to the answer. The reason why I thought it was the weird situation is the different results even if I explicitly set both dtypes to float32. I will check the github issue :)